# Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Copy of Subscribe to changes for viewers

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting error notifications every day, like below

/**********************************************************************************
From: 
Date: 27 June 2012 16:16
Subject: Summary of failures for Google Apps Script: Copy of Subscribe to changes for viewers
To: uwcsea@gapps.uwcsea.edu.sg

Your script, Copy of Subscribe to changes for viewers, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document Subscribe to changes for viewers : Garage Sales.

Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
6/27/12 4:15 PM     send_changes    Data storage error (line 5) time-based  6/27/12 4:16 PM

Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2012 Google 
********************************************************************************/

This is one of the error that I'm getting - http://screencast.com/t/QCRBCKxHRFGx

Need help urgently.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try running the function under the trigger manually and debug the problem. The Data Storage error among others occurs when you attempt to write a null to a Script/User Property.

Its hard to say why the error shown in the screenshot occurs but if you can put in some code here that may be helpful